# Image Map not working outside first Tab on same Page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I use many image maps to help our customers find their needed parts!
They work without problems when they all have their own page!
But if they are in a tab and that tab is not the first tab loaded, they don't work!

I suspect it has something to do with the calculation of the coordinates, since the image is not loaded at that point, so some information are missing!

And since i want the Map to be responsive i cant use fixed values for the Images

Just to clarify:

- The image is loaded, but not placed correctly.
- The areas work at the correct (missplaced) position, but the zoom function doesn't work because the image flies out of the frame
- The image panner doesn't work either

Live Demo: https://www.outrun-team.de/traxxas-support-1-16-anleitungen-explosionszeichnungen
just open 2nd or 3rd tab an u can see the Problem

What I need:

Help to make the maps work inside the tabs when the tab is open.

Code:
All the code for the clickable image map with zoom function and image panner.

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    if ($('.pancontainer') && $('.pancontainer').length > 0) {
        panExplosion();
        calcCoorsToImgWidth();
    }

    $('.cart-summary .lpa-button').css('display','none');

});





var calcCoorsToImgWidth = function () {

    $("map.exploded-view-map area").map(function () {
        var imgWidth = $('.pancontainer img[usemap="#exploded_map1"]').width(),
                imgWidthReference = 940,
                imgWidthRatio = imgWidthReference / imgWidth,
                coordsArr = $(this).attr('data-coords');

        coordsArr = coordsArr.split(',');

        for (var i = 0; i < coordsArr.length; i++) {
            coordsArr[i] = parseInt(parseInt(coordsArr[i]) / imgWidthRatio);
        }

        $(this).attr('data-coords', coordsArr.join(',')).attr('coords', coordsArr.join(','));
    });
};

function explodedPartPopup(art_number) {

    

    
    window.open('navi.php?qs=' + art_number + '', '_blank');

}

var ddimagepanner = {

    
    magnifyicons: ['<img class="zoomcontrols reset" src="/bilder/icons/magnify3.png" style="right: 85px; bottom: 5px; z-index: 1000; cursor: pointer; opacity: 1;" title="Zoom In" />, <img class="zoomcontrols in" src="/bilder/icons/magnify.png" style="right: 40px; bottom: 5px; z-index: 1000; cursor: pointer; opacity: 1;" title="Zoom In" />', '<img class="zoomcontrols out" src="/bilder/icons/magnify2.png" style="right: 5px; bottom: 5px; z-index: 1000; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0.7;" title="Zoom Out" />'],
    maxzoom: 4, 

    init: function ($, $img, options) {
        var s = options
        s.imagesize = [$img.width(), $img.height()]
        s.oimagesize = [$img.width(), $img.height()] 
        s.pos = (s.pos == "center") ? [-(s.imagesize[0] / 2 - s.wrappersize[0] / 2), -(s.imagesize[1] / 2 - s.wrappersize[1] / 2)] : [0, 0] 
        s.pos = [Math.floor(s.pos[0]), Math.floor(s.pos[1])]
        $img.css({position: 'absolute', left: s.pos[0], top: s.pos[1]})
        if (s.canzoom == "yes") { 
            s.dragcheck = {h: (s.wrappersize[0] > s.imagesize[0]) ? false : true, v: (s.wrappersize[1] > s.imagesize[1]) ? false : true} 
            s.$statusdiv = $('<div style="position:absolute;color:white;background:#353535;padding:2px 10px;font-size:12px;visibility:hidden">1x Magnify</div>').appendTo(s.$pancontainer) 
            s.$statusdiv.css({left: 0, top: s.wrappersize[1] - s.$statusdiv.outerHeight(), display: 'none', visibility: 'visible'})
            this.zoomfunct($, $img, s)
        }
        this.dragimage($, $img, s)
    },

    dragimage: function ($, $img, s) {
        $img.bind('mousedown touchstart', function (e) {
            var e = (e.type.indexOf('touch') != -1) ? e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0] : e
            s.pos = [parseInt($img.css('left')), parseInt($img.css('top'))]
            var xypos = [e.clientX, e.clientY]
            $img.bind('mousemove.dragstart touchmove.dragstart', function (e) {
                var e = (e.type.indexOf('touch') != '-1') ? e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0] : e
                var pos = s.pos, imagesize = s.imagesize, wrappersize = s.wrappersize
                var dx = e.clientX - xypos[0] 
                var dy = e.clientY - xypos[1] 
                s.dragcheck = {h: (wrappersize[0] > imagesize[0]) ? false : true, v: (wrappersize[1] > imagesize[1]) ? false : true}
                if (s.dragcheck.h == true) 
                    var newx = (dx > 0) ? Math.min(0, pos[0] + dx) : Math.max(-imagesize[0] + wrappersize[0], pos[0] + dx) 
                if (s.dragcheck.v == true) 
                    var newy = (dy > 0) ? Math.min(0, s.pos[1] + dy) : Math.max(-imagesize[1] + wrappersize[1], pos[1] + dy) 
                $img.css({left: (typeof newx != "undefined") ? newx : pos[0], top: (typeof newy != "undefined") ? newy : pos[1]})
                return false 
            })
            return false 
        })
        jQuery(document).bind('mouseup touchend', function (e) {
            var e = (e.type.indexOf('touch') != -1) ? e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0] : e
            $img.unbind('mousemove.dragstart touchmove.dragstart')
        })
    },

    zoomfunct: function ($, $img, s) {

        var magnifyicons = this.magnifyicons
        var $zoomimages = $(magnifyicons.join(''))
                .css({zIndex: 1000, cursor: 'pointer', opacity: 0.7})
                .attr("title", "Zoom Out")
                .appendTo(s.$pancontainer)
        $zoomimages.eq(2).css({opacity: 1})
                .attr("title", "Zoom In")
        $zoomimages.eq(0).css({opacity: 0.7})
                .attr("title", "Zoom Reset")

        $zoomimages.click(function (e) { 

            var $zimg = $(this) 
            var curzoom = s.curzoom 
            var zoomtype = ($zimg.attr("title").indexOf("In") != -1) ? "in" : "out"
            zoomtype = ($zimg.attr("title").indexOf("Reset") != -1) ? "reset" : zoomtype;

            if (zoomtype == "in" && s.curzoom == ddimagepanner.maxzoom || zoomtype == "out" && s.curzoom == 1) 
                return
            var basepos = [s.pos[0] / curzoom, s.pos[1] / curzoom]
            var newzoom = (zoomtype == "out") ? Math.max(1, curzoom - 1) : Math.min(ddimagepanner.maxzoom, curzoom + 1) 
            newzoom = (zoomtype == "reset") ? 1 : newzoom;

            $zoomimages.css("opacity", 1)
            if (newzoom == 1) { 
                $zoomimages.eq(3).css("opacity", 0.7);
                $zoomimages.eq(0).css("opacity", 0.7);
            } else if (newzoom == ddimagepanner.maxzoom) 
                $zoomimages.eq(2).css("opacity", 0.7)
            clearTimeout(s.statustimer)
            s.$statusdiv.html(newzoom + "x Zoom").show() 
            var nd = [s.oimagesize[0] * newzoom, s.oimagesize[1] * newzoom]
            var newpos = [basepos[0] * newzoom, basepos[1] * newzoom]
            newpos = [(zoomtype == "in" && s.wrappersize[0] > s.imagesize[0] || zoomtype == "out" && s.wrappersize[0] > nd[0]) ? s.wrappersize[0] / 2 - nd[0] / 2 : Math.max(-nd[0] + s.wrappersize[0], newpos[0]),
                (zoomtype == "in" && s.wrappersize[1] > s.imagesize[1] || zoomtype == "out" && s.wrappersize[1] > nd[1]) || zoomtype == "reset" ? s.wrappersize[1] / 2 - nd[1] / 2 : Math.max(-nd[1] + s.wrappersize[1], newpos[1])]
            $img.animate({width: nd[0], height: nd[1], left: newpos[0], top: newpos[1]}, function () {
                s.statustimer = setTimeout(function () {
                    s.$statusdiv.hide()
                }, 500)
            })
            s.imagesize = nd
            s.curzoom = newzoom
            s.pos = [newpos[0], newpos[1]]

            jQuery("area", $(this).parents('.pancontainer').siblings('.exploded-view-map')).each(function () {
                var pairs = jQuery(this).attr("data-coords").split(', ');
                for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
                    var nums = pairs[i].split(',');
                    for (var j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
                        nums[j] = ((parseFloat(nums[j])) * s.curzoom);
                    }
                    pairs[i] = nums.join(',');
                }
                jQuery(this).attr("coords", pairs.join(', '));
            });
        })
    }
}


jQuery.fn.imgmover = function (options) {
    var $ = jQuery
    return this.each(function () { 
        if (this.tagName != "IMG")
            return true 
        var $imgref = $(this)
        if (parseInt(this.style.width) > 0 && parseInt(this.style.height) > 0) 
            ddimagepanner.init($, $imgref, options)
        else if (this.complete) { 
            ddimagepanner.init($, $imgref, options)
        } else {
            $imgref.bind('load', function () {
                ddimagepanner.init($, $imgref, options)
            })
        }
    })
}
var panExplosion = function () {

    var $pancontainer = $('.pancontainer')
    $pancontainer.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this).css({
            position: 'relative',
            overflow: 'hidden',
            height: '675px'
        }) 

        var $img = $this.find('img:eq(0)') 
        $img.css({
            maxWidth: 'none',
            width: $this.width()
        });

        var options = {
            $pancontainer: $this,
            
            pos: $this.attr('data-orient'),
            
            curzoom: 1,
            canzoom: $this.attr('data-canzoom'),
            canzoom: 'yes',
            wrappersize: [$this.width(), $this.height()]
        }
        $img.imgmover(options)
    })

};


ajaxCall = function (urlAction, daten, callback) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: urlAction,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: daten,
        async: true,
        success: function (response) {
            callback(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(thrownError);
        }
    });
};
function uniqueArray(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
```

Some Map code Sample

```
<div class="pancontainer" data-orient="center" data-canzoom="yes" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;"> <img src="https:outrun-team.de/traxxas/explomaps/65465676.jpg" usemap="#exploded_map12"> </div>
<map name="exploded_map12" id="exploded_map12" class="exploded-view-map"> <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7061X');" coords="103,310,137,320" data-coords="103,310,137,320">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7061');" coords="103,302,119,311" data-coords="103,302,119,311">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7056');" coords="695,523,712,532" data-coords="695,523,712,532">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7056');" coords="645,490,661,499" data-coords="645,490,661,499">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7056');" coords="553,436,571,445" data-coords="553,436,571,445">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7056');" coords="472,392,490,400" data-coords="472,392,490,400">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7056');" coords="544,264,562,274" data-coords="544,264,562,274">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7150');" coords="607,148,624,157" data-coords="607,148,624,157">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7054');" coords="803,275,820,284" data-coords="803,275,820,284">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7057');" coords="350,381,367,389" data-coords="350,381,367,389">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7057');" coords="790,584,808,593" data-coords="790,584,808,593">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7057');" coords="685,379,702,389" data-coords="685,379,702,389">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7057');" coords="347,238,364,248" data-coords="347,238,364,248">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7057');" coords="347,83,364,91" data-coords="347,83,364,91">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7151X');" coords="676,135,712,145" data-coords="676,135,712,145">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7151');" coords="676,127,693,136" data-coords="676,127,693,136">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7057');" coords="768,520,789,537" data-coords="768,520,789,537">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7057');" coords="444,340,465,358" data-coords="444,340,465,358">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7057');" coords="659,312,680,330" data-coords="659,312,680,330">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7057');" coords="439,184,460,202" data-coords="439,184,460,202">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7057');" coords="431,29,453,48" data-coords="431,29,453,48">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7145');" coords="245,366,301,374" data-coords="245,366,301,374">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7146');" coords="245,356,296,364" data-coords="245,356,296,364">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7148');" coords="245,346,302,356" data-coords="245,346,302,356">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7147');" coords="245,336,297,346" data-coords="245,336,297,346">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7066X');" coords="243,230,278,239" data-coords="243,230,278,239">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7066');" coords="243,223,264,232" data-coords="243,223,264,232">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7063T');" coords="233,179,268,188" data-coords="233,179,268,188">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7063');" coords="233,171,249,179" data-coords="233,171,249,179">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7062');" coords="237,415,254,425" data-coords="237,415,254,425">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7067');" coords="243,129,260,137" data-coords="243,129,260,137">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7065');" coords="249,474,266,484" data-coords="249,474,266,484">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7065');" coords="245,287,263,297" data-coords="245,287,263,297">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7065');" coords="237,80,254,89" data-coords="237,80,254,89">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7062');" coords="238,142,255,151" data-coords="238,142,255,151">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7062');" coords="240,106,256,115" data-coords="240,106,256,115">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7062');" coords="240,568,256,577" data-coords="240,568,256,577">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7062');" coords="268,522,285,531" data-coords="268,522,285,531">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7065');" coords="268,513,285,523" data-coords="268,513,285,523">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7028');" coords="268,506,285,515" data-coords="268,506,285,515">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7028X');" coords="251,68,286,76" data-coords="251,68,286,76">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7062');" coords="251,59,268,68" data-coords="251,59,268,68">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7065');" coords="251,50,268,60" data-coords="251,50,268,60">
    <area shape="rect" href="javascript:explodedPartPopup('7028');" coords="251,43,268,52" data-coords="251,43,268,52">
</map>

<style>
.pancontainer {
    width: 940px;
    height: 675px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1.1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    left: -1rem;
    right: -1rem;
    top: -1rem;
    bottom: -1rem;
    margin: 35px 0px;
}

.pancontainer:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    left: -1rem;
    right: -1rem;
    top: -1rem;
    bottom: -1rem;
}

.pancontainer .zoomcontrols {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 996px) {
    .pancontainer {
        width: 940px;
        height: 675px
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .pancontainer {
        width: 100% !important;
        overflow-x: scroll !important;
    }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

this did the trick!

```
s.imagesize = [$('.tab-content>.active .pancontainer img').width(), $('.tab-content>.active .pancontainer img').height()]
```